# Обобщенное изменение State в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Подскажите пожалуйста, казалось бы вопрос простой и на JS его легко сделать. А вот как перевести на TypeScript не понимаю.

Имеется интерфейс

```
interface ILoginUser {
    Email: string;
    Password: string;
}
```

пишу обобщенный метод, который бы можно было применить к двум Input. Сейчас это два метода:

```
class Login extends React.Component<{}, ILoginUser> {

    public state: ILoginUser = {
        Email: "",
        Password: "",
    };

    public ChangeEmail = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        this.setState({
            Email: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    public ChangePassword = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        this.setState({
            Password: e.target.value,
        });
    };

render{}
```

И вот их хочу объединить в один чтобы не плодить копипаст. На JS это делается в пару строчек:

```
private handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        
    const { name , value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

Ошибка на этой строке:

```js
 this.setState({ [name]: value });
```

Сам текст ошибки:

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ILoginUser | Pick<ILoginUser, "Email" | "Password"> | ((prevState: Readonly, props: Readonly<{}>) => ILoginUser | Pick<ILoginUser, "Email" | "Password"> | null) | null'. Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<ILoginUser, "Email" | "Password">': Email, Password

Но TypeScript не даст так просто такую манипуляцию провести без типизирования. И вот как это типизировать правильно я не знаю. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то почему ошибка? Приведите код, который вызывает ошибку.

Comment: Ошибка на этой строке: this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });

TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ILoginUser | Pick<ILoginUser, "Email" | "Password"> | ((prevState: Readonly<ILoginUser>, props: Readonly<{}>) => ILoginUser | Pick<ILoginUser, "Email" | "Password"> | null) | null'.   Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<ILoginUser, "Email" | "Password">': Email, Password

Comment: Перенесите ошибку в вопрос.

Comment: Как именно используется интерфейс? Как определен `state`?

Comment: попробуй `public state: Partial<ILoginUser>`

Comment: +1 Вот теперь вопрос оформлен отлично! И ответ поспел)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что у вас используются разные типы, хотя казалось бы, что они полность совместимы. Допустим у вас `state` объявлен как `ILoginUser`, то `TypeScript` будет от вас требовать полный тип `ILoginUser` или его "неполную" версию (`Pick`).

Но в вашем коде `this.setState({ [name]: value });` вы передаете некий объект, который имеет тип `{ [x: string]:string }`. Т.е. компилятор не знает, что у вас в качестве `name` будут строго `Email` | `Password`, с его стороны туда может быть передана любая строка, поэтому он и не разрешает такой код.

Это можно поправить явным приведением типов:

```
private handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const newState = { [name]: value } as Pick<ILoginUser, keyof ILoginUser>;

    this.setState(newState);
}
```

или при помощи ([оператора `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)):

```
private handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({ ...this.state, [name]: value });
}
```

Comment: Премного благодарен, как за объяснение, так и за возможные решения